# Why does $ \int _1 ^3 \frac x {(x^2-9)^{4/3}}dx$ diverge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Could someone please explain to me why the following integral is diverging? And how you would go about proving that it is.
$$
 \int_1^3 \frac{x}{(x^2-9)^{4/3}}dx
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Substituting $x^2-9=t \; \Rightarrow \; 2xdx=dt$ the integral becomes
$$
\int_{-9}^0 \frac{1}{2}t^{-4/3} dt
$$

so you can easily find the primitive and see that it diverge for $t \to 0$.

Comment: Just curious, need the change of variable itself be justified?

Comment: The fact that a factor $x$ is in the integral suggest to try with a function of $x$ that has as derivative  something as $ax$, so a substitution of the form $t=kx^2+h$ and a look  at the denominator suggest the right substitution.